# Perl Grep in ssh2->exec not finding anything

Tags: regex, linux, perl, ssh, grep

I designed a program that goes through every log file in different Solaris (Unix) boxes in all of my applications and looks for a certain error. So, I designed the program like this:

```
my $ssh2 = Net::SSH2->new();
$ssh2->connect($host) or die "Unable to connect Host $@ \n";
$ssh2->auth_keyboard($user,$pass) or die "Unable to login $@ \n";

$chan1 = $ssh2->channel();
$chan1->exec("find /apps/appName/loc/Logs/server/ -type f | xargs grep \"CVS Call\" ");
while(<$chan1>) {
    print $_ . "\n";
}
```

If I were to grep for one word (just 'CVS'), it works. However, the second I add a space or a dot it does not find anything. I tried replacing the space with [[:space:]], or [:space:] but it still does not show any results. I know for a fact that the log files contain this error.

I also tried:

```
$chan1->exec("find /apps/appName/loc/Logs/server/ -type f -exec grep 'CVS Call' '{}' \\; -print");
```

I get the same results with this command, works find with only one word, as soon as I add the second word, it does not show any results.

Does anyone have any idea as to why when I add a space in the grep search it does not find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is probably related to the several levels of quoting required. Doing it by hand right is quite hard.

If you are on a Linux/Unix box, you could use [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH) which would do the quoting for you:

```
 my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host, user => $user, password => $password);
 my @lines = $ssh->capture('find', $logs_dir,
                           '-type', 'f',
                           '-exec', 'grep', '-q', $string, '{}', ';',
                           '-print');

 for (@lines) {
     ...
 }
```